# DP Solution Not Caching Properly - Time Out Error when input is ~70

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, optimization, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/divisor-game/

My recursion itself seems to work but I get a time out error when the input is large enough ~ 70. I tried doing memoization to cache the previous solutions but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure why.

```
 /**
     * @param {number} n
     * @return {boolean}
     */
    var divisorGame = function(n) {
       return helper(n);
    };
    
    const helper = (n, cache = {}) => {
        if(n === 1) return false;
        if(n in cache) return cache[n];
      
        
        for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(n % i === 0) {
                if(helper(n - 1) === false) return cache[n] = true;
            } 
        }
        
        return cache[n] = false;
        
    }
```

Comment: @ggorlen Ahh oops. I've corrected it to   if(n in cache) return cache[n];  But I'm still getting a timeout error in the same type of input

Comment: @ggorlen ok edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems you had were:

1. Starting the loop from `i = 0` whereas the question clearly said `0 < i < n`.
2. The question said that after choosing `i`, you need to replace current `n` with `n - i` but you called for `helper(n-1)`.

Below is the implementation of AC code with the above mentioned errors fixed.

```
var divisorGame = function(n) {
   return helper(n);
};

const cache = [];

function helper(n){
    if(n === 1) return false;
    if(n in cache) return cache[n];

    for(let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if(n % i === 0) {
            if(helper(n-i) == false){
                return cache[n] = true;
            }
        } 
    }
    return cache[n] = false;
}
```